# Save Email Attachments with Received Time and Sender Name

Tags: vba, datetime, outlook

**Problem:** Saving multiple attachments from email with same file name saves one attachment to folder

**Possible Solution:** Add received time and sender’s name to new file name.
I have VBA code I found on the internet that works. It seems there are multiple ways to do this and not all work with my code. I don’t want to run a rule script if possible.

I use the VBA code below in Outlook 365. It saves email attachments of selected emails.

The macro doesn't pick up attachments with the same name. For example, I will have multiple attachments called "image.pdf" but it only saves one attachment with that name and file type. I'm thinking I can add the Received Date and Time as well as the Sender's Name to the file name to make the file name unique. When I try this I get errors.

There are two macros. "Save_Emails_TEST" finds the folder I have designated and then calls "SaveAttachments" that saves the attachments.

**Request:** How do I add the received date and time, sender's name, and original file name as the new file name?

```
Public Sub Save_Emails_TEST()
strFolderpath = "H:\Saved Email Attachments\Test\"
SaveAttachments
End Sub

Private Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objOL = Application

    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    ' Check each selected item for attachments.
    For Each objMsg In objSelection

    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.count
        
    If lngCount > 0 Then
    
    ' Use a count down loop for removing items
    ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
    ' confused and only every other item is removed.
    
    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
    
    ' Get the file name.
    strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
    
    ' Combine with the path to the folder.
    strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
    
    ' Save the attachment as a file.
    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
    
    Next i
    End If
    
    Next
    
ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling#On_Error_Resume_Next.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim date_now As Date
Dim dateStamp As String
Dim LRandomNumber As Integer

For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
    
    ' Get the file name.
    strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
    
    LRandomNumber = Int((300 - 200 + 1) * Rnd + 200)
    date_obj =  objMsg.ReceivedTime ' Now()
    dateStamp = Format(date_obj, "yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss")

     ' Combine with the path to the folder.
    strFile = strFolderpath & dateStamp & LRandomNumber & strFile

    ' Save the attachment as a file.
    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

Next i
```